# Google chrome no blur on color input

Tags: html, google-chrome

A color picker input (type = color) will be rendered as a textbox in firefox as it has no native support, on Chrome however the browser will render a much nicer native control. However  using jQuery to bind to the `blur` event will work in firefox but not in chrome.

Is this not (yet) implemented or should I use a different event?

Here is a jsFiddle with the code in question (works in FF not in chrome) http://jsfiddle.net/Rgu6h/13/

Comment: ... it works in my chrome...? do you have some special settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the problem, what I want to know is if the value is changed, so I can just bind to the change event instead of the click/blur/mouseup or whatever event. Sometimes the solution is just too obvious.

Comment: I know but you can only do so after a day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can download modernizr.js and ask whether input type color is supported by the browser. If it is not, then you will write the function to display a color picker on blur.

This concept is called 'polyfills' which consists of creating extra functions when a browser doesn't natively supports it.

Have a look at Modernizr's website: http://modernizr.com/ to learn more. Just in case, you don't need to download the whole packag, you can select only the stuff that you need. In your case it will be a 9k file. (http://modernizr.com/docs/#inputtypes)

Update 1:
It seems like I misunderstood your question.

Update 2: 
It seems like chrome treats the input type color as a button. Why don't you use "click" event?

Comment: I know about modernizr, but thx for the tip. My problem is, if the color control is rendered. Funny enough, your answer did ring a bell (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Blur works. Try accessing the input with the TAB key on your keyboard, you'll see it's focused, then blurred, and the div shows up.

You may want to use `onmouseup`. That depends on exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Tab works, but not all end users will use TAB to navigate input controls (actually most ofhtem won't).
If I change it to onmouseup I still don't get the event to fire?